# VBA - Using .NET class library

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, com

We have a custom class library that has been built from the ground up that performs a variety of functions that are required for the business model in place. We also use VBA to automate some data insertion from standard Microsoft packages and from SolidWorks.

To date we have basically re-written the code in the VBA application macro's, but now are moving to include the class library into the VBA references. We've registered the class library for COM interop, and made sure that it is COM visible. The file is referencable, we have added the `<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)> _` tag above each of the Public Classes, so that intellisense 'works'.

With that said, the problem now arises - when we reference the class library, for this instance let's call it `Test_Object`, it is picked up and seems to work just fine. So we go ahead and try a small sample to make sure it's using the public functions and returning expected values:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim test As New Test_Object.Formatting
    Dim t As String
    t = test.extractNumber("abc12g3y45")
    Target.Value = t
End Sub
```

This works as expected, returning 12345 in the selected cell/s.

However, when I try a different class, following the exact same procedure, I get an error (`Object variable or With block variable not set`). Code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim test As New Test_Object.SQLCalls
    Dim t As String
    t = test.SQLNumber("SELECT TOP 1 ID from testdb.dbo.TESTTABLE") 'where the string literal in the parentheses is a parameter that is passed.
    Target.Value = t
End Sub
```

This fails on the `t = test.SQLNumber` line. It also fails on another function within that `SQLCalls` class, a function that returns the date in SQL format (so it is not anything to do with the connection to the database).

Can anyone assist in what could be causing this error? I've googled for hours to no avail, and am willing to try whatever it takes to get this working.

Cheers.

**EDIT: (added in the `.SQLNumber()` method)**

```
Function SQLNumber(query As String) As Double
    Dim tno As Double
        Try
            Using SQLConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(Connection_String_Current)
                SQLConnection.Open()
                SQLCommand = New SqlCommand(query, SQLConnection)
                tno = SQLCommand.ExecuteScalar
            End Using
        Catch ex As System.Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    Return tno
End Function
```

For comparison, the `extractNumber()` method:

```
Function extractNumber(extstr As String) As Double
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    Dim tempstr As String
    Dim extno As String = ""
    Do Until i > Len(extstr)
        tempstr = Mid(extstr, i, 1)
        If tempstr = "0" Or tempstr = "1" Or tempstr = "2" Or tempstr = "3" Or tempstr = "4" Or tempstr = "5" Or tempstr = "6" Or tempstr = "7" Or tempstr = "8" Or tempstr = "9" Or tempstr = "." Then
            extno = extno & tempstr
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    If IsNumeric(extno) Then
        Return CDbl(extno)
    Else
        Return 0
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: You need to show the code for `.SQLNumber()` method and possibly the `.SQLCalls` class altogether.

Comment: I can enter in the `.SQLNumber()` method, however the whole class in itself is well over 1000 lines.

Comment: share `.SQLNumber()` with us please as I believe it may by crucial.

Comment: I've put in the `.SQLNumber()` method, and also the working `.extractNumber()` method for comparison. Thanks for your ongoing help.

Comment: Ok, first thing that I see is not right is the return type of `.SQLNumber()` method - it's `double` and you are trying to assign that to a `String t` in VBA. Are you aware of that?

Comment: Yessir. I have put mistakenly put that in there, however even when declaring as a double, it still causes the same issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62233/discussion-between-vba4all-and-deekayy90).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of vba4all, we managed to delve down right to the issue.

When I tried to create a new instance of an object using `Dim x as new Test_Object.SQLCalls`, I was completely oblivious to the fact that I had not re-entered this crucial line:
`<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)> _`.

Prior to doing this, I had this in my object explorer which has both the ISQLCalls and SQLCalls in the Classes section 
[image]

But wait, ISQLCalls isn't a class, it's an interface!

By entering the `<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)> _` back in the SQLCalls class, the object explorer looked a bit better:

[image]

And low and behold, I could now create a new instance of the class, and the methods were exposed.

tldr:
I needed to explicitly declare the interface and use `<InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)>` on the interface and `<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)>` on the class.

Many thanks to vba4all, who selflessly devoted their time to assist in this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, didn't notice that the link was defunct. The answer of the question is in the body so no need for a link to the old page.